# SQL Order By Non Existant Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I found what should be a bug in a query when it was copied to another (supposedly identical) database and it failed. It looks about like this

```
SELECT  a.columnOne ,
    b.columnOne
FROM TableOne a
INNER JOIN TableTwo b
    ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.Value = 0
ORDER BY a.ColumnOne ,
    b.ColumnTwo
```

The 'bug' is that TableTwo does NOT have a column named columnTwo (used in the ORDER BY clause), yet it runs fine. At least it does on one of the databases, the other one complains as it should. But I'm sure neither has a TableTwo.columnTwo.

It may be worth mentioning that TableOne DOES have a column named columnTwo.

It's an easy fix, but it's bugging me that this has existed for so long without any problems. Any idea what could be going on? (Or any more information I could give?)

Comment: This has to do with the **[Compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680(v=SQL.105).aspx)** In one case, the table alias is ignored, in the other it isn't (and the error is produced)

Comment: See the edited link, where it has the differences between level 80 and 90.

Comment: @ypercube Yep...apparently prefixes may be ignored in the ORDER BY list in 2000 compatibility mode. Thank you. Add this as an answer an I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

> WHEN binding the column references in the ORDER BY list to the columns
>   defined in the SELECT list, column ambiguities are ignored and column
>   prefixes are sometimes ignored. This can cause the result set to
>   return in an unexpected order. For example, an ORDER BY clause with a
>   single two-part column (.) that is used as a
>   reference to a column in a SELECT list is accepted, but the table
>   alias is ignored. Consider the following query. SELECT c1 = -c1 FROM
>   t_table AS x ORDER BY x.c1 When executed, the column prefix is ignored
>   in the ORDER BY. The sort operation does not occur on the specified
>   source column (x.c1) as expected; instead it occurs on the derived c1
>   column that is defined in the query. The execution plan for this query
>   shows that the values for the derived column are computed first and
>   then the computed values are sorted

Source - "MSDN"

Comment: Sorry but without explaining the context this doesn't make sense.